# Non-recursive combination algorithm to generate distinct character strings

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

This problem has been irritating me for too long. I need a non-recursive algorithm in `C` to generate non-distinct character strings. For instance, if a given character string is `26` characters long, and the string is of length `2`, then there are `26^2` non-distinct characters.

Please note that these are distinct combinations, `aab` is not the same as `baa` or `aba`. I've searched S.O., and most solutions produce non-distinct combinations. Also, I do not need permutations.

The algorithm can't rely on a libraries. I'm going to translate this C code into cuda where standard C libraries don't work (at least not efficiently).

Before I show you what I started, let me explain an aspect of the program. It is multithreaded on a GPU, so I initialize the beginning string with a few characters, `aa` in this case. To create a combination, I add one or more characters depending on the desired length.

Here's one method that I have attempted:

```
int main(void){

   //Declarations
   char final[12] = {0};
   char b[3] = "aa";
   char charSet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
   int max = 4; //Set for demonstration purposes
   int ul = 1;
   int k,i;

   //This program is multithreaded on a GPU. Each thread is initialized 
   //to a starting value for the string. In this case, it is aa

   //Set final with a starting prefix
   int pref = strlen(b);
   memcpy(final, b, pref+1);

   //Determine the number of non-distinct combinations
   for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) ul *= strlen(charSet);

   //Start concatenating characters to the current character string
   for(k = 0; k < ul; k++)
   {
        final[pref+1] = charSet[k];
        //Do some work with the string

   }
   ...
```

It should be obvious that this program does nothing useful, accept if I'm only appending one character from `charSet`.

My professor suggested that I try using a mapping (this isn't homework; I asked him about possible ways to generate distinct combinations without recursion).

His suggestion is similar to what I started above. Using the number of combinations calculated, he suggested to decompose it according to `mod 10`. However, I realized it wouldn't work.

For example, say I need to append two characters. This gives me 676 combinations using the character set above. If I am on the 523rd combination, the decomposition he demonstrated would yield

```
523 % 10 = 3
52 % 10 = 2
5 % 10 = 5
```

It should be obvious that this doesn't work. For one, it yields three characters, and two, if my character set is larger than 10 characters, the mapping ignores those above index 9.

Still, I believe a mapping is key to the solution.

The other method I explored utilized for loops:

```
//Psuedocode
c = charset;

for(i = 0; i <length(charset); i++){
    concat string

    for(j = 0; i <length(charset); i++){
          concat string

          for...
```

However, this hardcodes the length of the string I want to compute. I could use an `if` statement with a `goto` to break it, but I would like to avoid this method.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: How do you generate the numbers 0-9999 without recursion? Your problem is exactly the same except you're working base-26.

Comment: @R.. Don't know if this is what you mean, but I would simply do a for loop and increment some integer variable to the desired max.

Comment: Exactly. So your problem is how to do the same with a base-26 number represented in a character array. First work out on paper how you'd do it with a base-10 number working with the digits. Use leading zeros by the way, so 0 is 0000 or whatever.

Comment: @R.. and 1 is 0001. If that is the case, are you essentially suggesting assigning a unique number to each "character" as in a mapping? (Assuming we are still in base-10).

Comment: Well if you're doing it with base 10 numbers, yes, you first go from 0000 to 0001, then to 0002, and so on, until you get to 0009. What happens next?

Comment: 0010. I understand how bases work. I'm curious, though, what you have in mind for base-26. Specifically how that address my need to limit the length of the combinations that are appended to the initial string.

Comment: Well what happens when you go AAAA, AAAB, ..., AAAZ? Apply the same principle for what happens next.

Comment: If I understand fully, AABA occurs next. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Your distinct/non-distinct terminology is backwards.  If  “`aab` is not the same as `baa` or `aba`” then they are *distinct* rather than *non-distinct*

Comment: Apparently you already know how to do this with nested loops or recursion, but the nested loops can't work if `n` (the number of characters) is variable since you'd need `n` loops. The key step is realizing that you can always "increment" a decimal (or base-26) "number" without keeping track of where you are in the overall process. There's a well-defined procedure for how you get from the representation of "X" to the representation of "X+1".

Comment: @R..Yep, that's the problem with nested loops.

Comment: @jwpat7 I've heard it both ways in various forums. However, I'm inclined to agree with you now that you pointed that out.

Comment: @Mlagma: If I gave you the decimal number 3299 or the base-26 string FNZZ, what would the "next number" be after each? Note that you don't need any nested loops to keep track of where you are in stepping through all the values; you just have to know the procedure for how to get from "X" to "X+1".

Comment: I believe it would be FOAA - and the number, 3300.

Comment: So what's the process to get those answers?

Comment: @R.. In c, integers can simply be incremented. I just need to figure a process by which to increment different base systems. In my case, it may not be 26, it may be 52, 91, and so forth. But that shouldn't matter. In all honesty, I'm not certain. From what I can think of, I could loop through the string and increment the characters that need to be, since characters are represented by an integer ascii code.

Comment: The way you increment in decimal is to replace all the 9's (there may be none) at the end of the number with 0's and increment the place just before the 9's (may be the last place if there were no 9's at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Given a string, to find the next possible string in the sequence:

1. Find the last character in the string which is not the last character in the alphabet.
2. Replace it with the next character in the alphabet.
3. Change every character to the right of that character with the first character in the alphabet.

Start with a string which is a repetition of the first character of the alphabet. When step 1 fails (because the string is all the last character of the alphabet) then you're done.

Example: the alphabet is `"ajxz"`.

Start with `aaaa`.

First iteration: the rightmost character which is not `z` is the last one. Change it to the next character: `aaaj`

Second iteration. Ditto. `aaax`

Third iteration: Again. `aaaz`

Four iteration: Now the rightmost non-`z` character is the second last one. Advance it and change all characters to the right to `a`: `aaja`

Etc.

Comment: During finals week and days of sleep deprivation, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for everyone's input; it was helpful. Being that I am translating this algorithm into cuda, I need it to be as efficient as possible on a GPU. The methods proposed certainly work, but not necessarily optimal for GPU architecture. I came up with a different solution using modular arithmetic that takes advantage of the base of my character set. Here's an example program, primarily in `C` with a mix of `C++` for output, and it's fairly fast.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ull;

int main(void){

   //Declarations
   int init = 2;
   char final[12] = {'a', 'a'};

   char charSet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
   ull max = 2; //Modify as need be


   int base = strlen(charSet);
   int placeHolder; //Maps to character in charset (result of %)
   ull quotient;  //Quotient after division by base

   ull nComb = 1;
   char comb[max+1]; //Array to hold combinations

   int c = 0;
   ull i,j;


   //Compute the number of distinct combinations ((size of charset)^length)
   for(j = 0; j < max; j++) nComb *= strlen(charSet);


   //Begin computing combinations
   for(i = 0; i < nComb; i++){
       quotient = i;

      for(j = 0; j < max; j++){ //No need to check whether the quotient is zero
             placeHolder = quotient % base;
             final[init+j] = charSet[placeHolder]; //Copy the indicated character
             quotient /= base; //Divide the number by its base to calculate the next character
      }

      string str(final);
      c++;
      //Print combinations
      cout << final << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n\n" << c << " combinations calculated";
  getchar();
}
```